# Calculating two numbers from command line c++

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

This is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int frstNumb = atoi (argv[1]);
  int scndNumb = atoi (argv[2]);
  int sum = 0;
  sum = frstNumb + scndNumb;
}
```

Okay, now its working for integers. What do I must do so I can put e.g. "2.5 and 1.2" in my parameters? This program won't calculate that kind of numbers. Help?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to use only STL or is it fine to also use Boost, for example? ...

Comment: sounds very much like a homework question

Comment: indent every line by 4 spaces please. STL or Boost; funny.

Comment: What should it do after you add them?  Print them to the screen?  Why doesn't the above work for you?  Please try to include as much information in your question as possible.

Comment: @Tom: So what? The OP has obviously tried and encountered difficulties so we help him. It's not like he's asking us to do his HW

Comment: @Armen sounds to me like he's asking us to do it, and 3 out of the 3 answers do so, including yours

Comment: @Armen i dont really care lol

Comment: @Tom: I'm sure you don't

Comment: Beside Bojan Komazec's answer, which is blatantly bad because it gives away a complete answer without explanations for the learner, all other answers so far are instructive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep-- you want `atoi()`.

```
int frstNumb = atoi(argv[1]);
int scndNumb = atoi(argv[2]);
```

I'd suggest googling `atoi()` to see how it works, it will probably help you in the future.

Comment: Thanks. 
Yes, this helped.
And I have 1 more question, please. 
What if i would like to enter "1.20" as my number? How can I use float, when my argument is char?

Answer (score 5):

The arguments are always passed as strings. First of all, change the main function declaration to

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
```

Note that the return value of main MUST be int, otherwise it is nonstandard.

Second convert `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` to integers with either `atoi` , which, to my taste, is a bit C-ish, although the simplest, or by `boost::lexical_cast`

e.g.

```
int i1 = atoi(argv[1]); //#include <cstdlib>
int i1 = boost::lexical_cast<int>(argv[1]); //#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
```

Answer (score 2):

`argv[1]` and `argv[2]` are strings. When you do the sum, wrap them with `atoi()` calls so they are parsed and converted to integers.

**Thanks to Mark Loeser and walkingTarget**

Your declaration of `main()` should be:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

`main()` should **always** return an `int`, and `argv` should **always** be an array of strings.

Comment: He's defined argv incorrectly as int's in his example, btw.  It should be char* argv[], I believe.

Comment: His entire declaration for `main()` is wrong.  `main()` is never a void :)

Comment: Whoops, I missed that. Thanks, I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: And where can I learn to parse to double/float ? Because, what if I enter 2.4 and 5.4 as my numbers ?

Comment: Use `atof()` instead of `atoi()`. `atof()` will parse the string as a double and return a double.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in other answers, you first need to change declaration of function `main` - `argc` represents total number of arguments passed to it and `argv` is an array of arguments themselves (each argument is an element in array; first element - `argv[0]` - is path to this executing binary! `argv[1]` is actually first argument from a command line).

Both in C and C++ you can use `atoi` or `sscanf` functions but in C++ you should take advantage of `STL stringstream`'s conversion capabilities:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{ 
    if(argc != 3)
    {
        cerr << "Invalid number of operands" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    int n1 = 0;
    int n2 = 0;

    stringstream ss; 
    ss << argv[1];      
    ss >> n1;   
    ss.clear();
    ss << argv[2];  
    ss >> n2;

    int sum = n1 + n2;  

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Voted down for giving away a complete answer without being instructive to the learner.

Comment: I was editing answer/adding explanation while being downwoted. I personally appreciate more code with the explanation so in general I agree with you